# C++ Map default argument typedef requirement

Tags: c++, templates, stl

It seems my compiler is dying on this code block below, and is only resolved once I typedef the map for the default constrcutor on GCC 4.1.2. Is there some C++ or GCC oddity I'm missing?

Error: (missing , or ... before < identifier)

```
class Blah
{
  static void dothis(std::map<int,int> mymap = std::map<int,int>());
}
```

Works:

```
class Blah
{
  typedef std::map<int,int> MapType;
  static void dothis(std::map<int,int> mymap = MapType());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some C++ or GCC oddity I'm missing?

Your code is legal, and your compiler is old. Try upgrading your compiler. Here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=8098d4fa66be27fc8d4627931af89a1b-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc) of your code compiling with GCC 4.8.0.